# Apply function modification to curried function

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, pure-function

This is based on [A function that modifies functions - well-defined operation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250066), a previous question of mine.

Lukas Lang's answer of course works very well, but now I encountered the following edge case:
What if I have a function with multiple arguments, say `f[x, y]`, and only want to apply my `linearize` function to the second argument?

I don't know how to approach this. Something like `linearize[ f[x_, #]& ]` gives me a `Tag Function is Protected` error, and I don't understand enough wolfram (yet) to get this.
Also, I thought maybe [`Curry`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) could be applied, but I couldn't immediately figure out how.

Is this possible?

---

**Edit while reviewing question:**
Of course, I could pass an optional `position` parameter to `linearize`, which would tell `linearize` to only linearize in that position. But that seems a bit messy (especially since my input function can have arbitrary arity and possibly optional arguments), and I would like to go for a more functional approach if possible.

Comment: You need to assign the definition to "f" by: `f /; linearize[f[x_, #] &] `

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem with `linearize[ f[x_, #]& ]` is that you are trying to define sub-values for `Function`: `f[x_, #]&` is equivalent to `Function[f[x_, #]]`, so `linearize` will try to do

```
Function[f[x_, #]][pre___, 0, ___] := 0
```

This attempts to assign the definition to `Function`, which is `Protected`, hence the error.

If you want some kind of a specification of which arguments should be linearized that is more explicit than a second argument with indices, I would suggest something like the following:

```
symbols = Alternatives[basisElement];
noSymbol := FreeQ[symbols]

Attributes[linearize] = {HoldFirst};
linearize[f_[spec___]] :=
  (ReplaceList[
     FixedPoint[
      Replace[Hold[pre___, ##, post___] :> Hold[pre, ___, #, ___, post]],
      Hold[spec]
     ],
     Hold[pre___, #, post___] :>
       Replace[
        Hold[PatternSequence[pre], PatternSequence[post]],
        # -> _,
        {2}
       ] /. Hold[pre2_, post2_] :> (
        f[pre2, 0, post2] := 0;
        f[pre3 : pre2, v_ + w_, post3 : post2] := f[pre3, v, post3] + f[pre3, w, post3];
        f[pre3 : pre2, a_*v_, post3 : post2] := a*f[pre3, v, post3] /; noSymbol[a];
       )
    ];);
linearize[f_] := linearize[f[##]]
```

The syntax is `linearize[f[spec]]`, where spec is a sequence of patterns and slots such as `f[__,#,_,#,_]`. Patterns can be any valid pattern and will not be linearized. `#` is a placeholder for a single argument that is to be linearized. Finally, `##` is a placeholder for 1 or more arguments that should all be linearized, so effectively `___, #, ___`.

Some examples of how to use it:

Linearize only the second of two arguments:

```
Clear[f]
linearize[f[_, #]]

{f[a basisElement, c + d], f[a basisElement], f[a basisElement, c + d, e + g]}
(* {f[a basisElement, c] + f[a basisElement, d], f[a basisElement], f[a basisElement, c + d, e + g]} *)
```

Linearize the first of 2 or more arguments:

```
Clear[f]
linearize[f[#, __]]

{f[a basisElement, c + d], f[a basisElement], f[a basisElement, c + d, e + g]}
(* {a f[basisElement, c + d], f[a basisElement], a f[basisElement, c + d, e + g]} *)
```

Linearize the first of any number of arguments:

```
Clear[f]
linearize[f[#, ___]]

{f[a basisElement, c + d], f[a basisElement], f[a basisElement, c + d, e + g]}
(* {a f[basisElement, c + d], a f[basisElement], a f[basisElement, c + d, e + g]} *)
```

Linearize all but the last argument:

```
Clear[f]
linearize[f[##, _]]

{f[a basisElement, c + d], f[a basisElement], f[a basisElement, c + d, e + g]}
(* {a f[basisElement, c + d], f[a basisElement], a f[basisElement, c, e + g] + a f[basisElement, d, e + g]} *)
```

As for how it works: The main idea is very similar to the linked question, but we have to be more careful constructing the `pre___` and `post___` patterns, since we want to restrict what they can match. It's probably best to just look at an example for the rest, and see what the different steps do. Let's look at `linearize[f[_, #, _, ##]]`, which linearizes arguments 2, 4, 5, 6, etc.:

This version of `linearize` prints some additional information:

```
Attributes[linearize] = {HoldFirst};
linearize[f_[spec___]] :=
  (ReplaceList[
     EchoFunction["  Replace ## with ___,#,___:", # &]@FixedPoint[
       Replace[Hold[pre___, ##, post___] :> Hold[pre, ___, #, ___, post]],
       EchoFunction["Original spec:", # &]@Hold[spec]
       ],
     Hold[pre___, #, post___] :> (
       Echo[{pre, Style[#, Red], post}, "    Process one slot:"];
       EchoFunction["      Replace remaining slots with _:", # &]@Replace[
          Hold[PatternSequence[pre], PatternSequence[post]],
          # -> _,
          {2}
          ] /. Hold[pre2_, post2_] :> (
          Echo[HoldForm[f][pre2, Style["###", Red], post], "        Pattern:"];
          f[pre2, 0, post2] := 0;
          f[pre3 : pre2, v_ + w_, post3 : post2] := f[pre3, v, post3] + f[pre3, w, post3];
          f[pre3 : pre2, a_*v_, post3 : post2] := a*f[pre3, v, post3] /; noSymbol[a];
          ))
     ];);
linearize[f_] := linearize[f[##]]

Clear[f];
linearize[f[_, #, _, ##]]
```

[image]

Comment: Oof, this will take me a while to digest. Thanks :)